# iOSのクラッシュログ解析で、.ipsファイルではなく.crashファイルで使用する方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

[「iOS15以降のクラッシュログ解析」](https://qiita.com/am10/items/63a4db08daf9dae3f80e)にて、symbolicatecrashではなくCrashSymbolicator.pyを使ってクラッシュログ解析する方法が書かれていました。

.ipsファイルがある場合、以下のようなコマンドでクラッシュログをシンボル化できるようです。

```
python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework/Resources/CrashSymbolicator.py -p foo.ips -d Foo.app.dSYM -o piyo.ips
```

ただ、私は.ipsファイルを見つける方法がわかりません。XCodeのOrganizerからユーザーのクラッシュログを解析するため、「Crashes」のところで右クリックから「Show in Finder」をクリックすると「xxxxx.crashpoint」というファイル群が表示されます。「xxxxx.crashpoint」を右クリックし「show package contents」をクリックすると「Filters」というフォルダーの中に「Logs」というフォルダーがあり、そこに「xxxxx.crash」というファイル群があるのは見つかります。

.crashファイルしか見つけることが出来ません。
しかし、.crashファイルを以下のようにCrashSymbolicator.pyでシンボル化しようとしてもエラーになります。

```
python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework/Resources/CrashSymbolicator.py -p foo.crash -d Foo.app.dSYM -o piyo.crash
```

エラー内容は以下のとおりです。

```
Crash log is missing bug_type field. Stopping symbolication.
```

次のように、symbolicatecrashを使ってもエラーになります。

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -d Foo.app.dSYM -o piyo.txt foo.crash
```

エラー内容は以下のとおりです。

```
No symbolic information found
```

どうすれば正しく.crashファイルをシンボル化できますか？